# Melhor forma de fazer preload em AngularJs num Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic, arquitetura-de-software

Estou com uma dúvida de arquitetura de apps.

tenho um projeto IONIC onde o app salva alguns dados básicos no local storage para não ter de pedir login do usuário toda vez que é aberto.

Porém esses dados são essenciais pro restante da aplicação.

atualmente eu tenho as seguintes rotas de entrada:

- 'app.home' -> quando os dados já existem no localstorage
- 'app.login' -> quando os dados não existem e é preciso fazer login.

o negócio é que é na rota 'app.home' que eu faço a verificação do localstorage e dalí decido se permaneço na rota ou direciono para 'app.login'. Só que na 'app.home' eu já preciso de dados que deveriam estar no localstorage, e quando quando redireciona pra login e depois volta pra home, essa view já havia sido carregada e os dados salvos depois do login não atualizam essa view.

Então pensei, 'qual seria a melhor forma de fazer, então, esse preloader dos dados e direcionar para login ou home comforma a necessidade?'.

Essa é a questão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é "na rota" que você faz a verificação do localStorage, é no controller dela.
Veja, você está executando um código que não pertence ao controller em questão.

Melhor seria definir qual é a rota a ser carregada antes de entrar em um controller específico:

```
angular.module('App', [ 'ionic',...])

.run(function($state) {

     //faça sua pesquisa na localstorage aqui
     if ( ... ) {
            $state.go('app.home');
     else {
            $state.go('app.login');
     }

});
```